# addClass active to slider thumb

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add an active class to img when .thumb is clicked.

**What I'm trying to do:**
[image]

**What I get:**
[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".thumb").click(function() {
var IMG = $(this).find("img").addClass('active');
$(".viewer").not($(this).siblings().find('img').removeClass('active').parent().after()).remove();

var top = $(this).offset().top - 10; 
// window.scrollTo(0, top); // no animation
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: top }, 100);

$(this).parent().after("<div class='viewer'><div class='content-slide'><img src='' /><p class='exit'>✖</p><h2></h2><span></span></div></div>");

$(".viewer").find("img").attr("src", IMG.attr("data-HD"));
$(".viewer").find("h2").text(IMG.attr("title"));
$(".viewer").find("span").text(IMG.attr("description"));
$(".content-slide img").height($(".viewer").height());
$("p.exit").click(function() {
$(this).closest(".viewer").slideUp(200, this.remove);
$("img").removeClass('active'); 
});
});

});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNrQWe

Comment: and what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the class while you are clicking on the thumbs,

```
var IMG = $("img").not($(this).find("img").addClass('active')).removeClass("active");
```

### [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNZeRL)

Comment: You're the best! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jakedk Glad to help! :)

Comment: Yikes, I just noticed that it's not displaying .viewer with this. Hmm, the first two thumbs seem to react but not the rest.

Comment: On my demo if you click on the thumbs it adds a div .viewer under it and in that there's a larger image of the thumbnail. Like this http://i.imgur.com/qEp0xNw.gif but when we remove class while clicking thumbs we get this http://i.imgur.com/8YbDZa0.gif do you know what's causing it?

Comment: @Jakedk :) By the way try to accept this answer if you feel that it has helped you. And this is not a compulsion. :)

Comment: That was quick! Yes, exactly. Thank you again, Rajaprabhu. Us newbie's need people like you.